# page limits on Mac printer

Tags: mac-osx, printing, printer, osx-snow-leopard, cups

How can I set limits on the number of pages which can be printed by a user on Mac OS, or the Server?

We have two printers on an all mac network. There are several Mac servers on the network and regular clients too. Currently the clients just send to the printers (HP network printers with their own internal print queues) and there are no page limits.

I would like to set a page limit, perhaps number of pages per month, for each user.

Comment: We'll need to know a LOT more information please, as much detail as you can.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the question is extremely vague and lacking alot of important information.

However, quotas per user can be managed with Workgroup Manager, and Individual queues can be enforced with Server Admin.

You can google search this and produce easily the manuals for administering this and other managed services.

If this information feels lacking, than please feel free to elaborate.